# Adding noise in simple signal

Tags: signal-processing, fft

I am trying to add phase noise in my signal and analyze the result in the frequency domain. However, I am not getting the desired output. Can anyone tell me what mistake I am making? Since I am applying phase noise, signal with phase noise should be broader than the original signal in frequency domain.

```
sig = cos(2*pi*30*t);             %%%% original signal
sig_fft = fft(sig);
figure,plot(abs(sig_fft));         
sig2 = sig + 2*awgn(1,length(t));  %%%%% adding phase noise
sig2_fft = fft(sig2);
figure,plot(abs(sig2_fft));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add phase noise you should be adding noise to the signal's phase rather than to the complete generated signal:

```
sig  = cos(2*pi*30*t);                            % original signal
sig2 = cos(2*pi*30*t + sigma*randn(1,length(t))); % signal with phase noise
```

where `sigma` is the standard deviation of the phase noise (the larger `sigma` the more noise you will be adding).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. Moreover, I can use same for the amplitude noise as well right?

```
A = sigma*randn(1,lenth(t)); %% amplitude noise
sig  = cos(2*pi*30*t);                            % original signal
sig2 = A*cos(2*pi*30*t + sigma*randn(1,length(t))); %signal with phase & amplitude noise
```